# OpenJPA inserting into one table data from another table

Tags: java, sql, openjpa

I am new to `OpenJPA`
I am trying to insert data into a table some of which comes from another table. Below is the scenario.

```
Table1: id, app_name, app_version, app_active  

Table2: id, app_name, app_version, dev_name, dev_Lastname, dev_shortname,

Pojo1 maps fields to column of table1  
Pojo2 maps fields to column of table2
```

Query:

```
insert into table2 ("dev_name","dev_lastname","dev_shortname") select t1.app_name, t1.app_version from Table1 t1 where t1.app_name = ?
```

i dont know how to run this query using **`Openjpa`** and how to map these fields to each other in two pojos. 
if I use the `Query object` then what about the **`pojos`**?? will they come in use?? I mean will i need to do **`transaction.save`**??

Any help with a sample code appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your query manipulates data directly in the database while JPA handles the object relationships.

Im not sure what problem you are trying to solve but can you read the Pojo1 convert it to a Pojo2 object that you just save?

Edit:
In you java application first retrieve your Pojo1 from the entity manager with some query.
Then Construct corresponding Pojo2 objects with the fields you want from Pojo1. Then just to entityManager.persist with your new Pojo2 objects.

This is quite complex to perform what you showed could be made in a one line sql statement.

Comment: I have to insert data into table 2 but need to pick 3 columns from table 1. what do u mean by convert pojo1 to pojo2 object. can u please give some example? Thanks

Comment: Thanks Dan, that came to my mind but I think it will be slow and when I have to insert a bunch of data, running the for loop for it will be tedious to match each entry. Can you suggest some workaround to this?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040969/how-can-i-move-an-object-from-one-table-to-another-using-openjpa?rq=1